# SQLSTATE[42000] UPDATE Sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, sql-update

I have this error but I don't understand why :(

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Match = 1 WHERE
>   Utilisateur_idUtilisateur = 1' at line 1' in
>   C:\wamp\www\Sitepersonnelle\AjouterMatch.php on line 14

And here is my SQL req

```
$bdd->exec("UPDATE classement SET Match =+ 1 WHERE Utilisateur_idUtilisateur = $JoueurDomicile");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`match` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL. Either use backticks to escape it or use another name for your column.

```
UPDATE classement
SET `Match` = `Match` + 1 
WHERE Utilisateur_idUtilisateur = '$JoueurDomicile'
```

And if `$JoueurDomicile` is a string then put quotes around it.
And there is no `=+` operator in MySQL, nor in any other lanuage it know.